# Install oracle client 32 bit on Windows Server 2012 64 bit

Tags: oracle11g

I have installed 64 bit oracle(11.2g) on windows server 2012 64 bit.

When I try to install 32 bit oracle client on windows server 2012 64 bit, I get only the following directories in my install.

```
cfgtoollogs  
install  
inventory  
jdbc  
light  
odbc  
rdbms
```

Any suggestions please?

Answer (score 0):

Why do you think that's a problem?  You're installing the *client* not the entire database. The client install is a minimal install consisting of basic libraries required to connect to the database

Comment: But its missing directories eg 'Network' directory which is suppose to have tnsnames.ora

Comment: @user2837961 so create them. Client installs are minimal installs, with just the required set of files

Comment: It does connect using sqlplus. But for my application to connect I need OraOLEDB11.dll which is usually in the bin folder of the client. It does not have bin folder either. Does this mean I should copy the client dlls as well (from another machine)

Comment: The real question should be why are you installing oracle client when the server is installed? That doesnt make any sense.

Comment: You are right. The problem is bigger. I have installed Oracle 64 bit but my software is 32 bit. So I am trying to install 32 bit client so that my software can connect to oracle

Comment: @user2837961 that is irrelevant, you can connect to 64-bit Oracle from your 32-bit application & vice versa. What you need is the right version of the client from where your app is available. If you app is on another system, the client should be installed on the same system where the app is - not on the the server

Comment: My Client sits on the server. That is why I am trying to install oracle client on the same server machine. This is an old legacy system and I cannot change the way it works. Currently I have to install oracle client for it to work because of 64 bit oracle